# Get contents of first and last row of csv file

Tags: .net, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with more than 3000+ rows, but I would like to read/get contents of only the first entry and the last entry.

I have 3 columns: BatchID, Transprinted, and Date. I am unable to map the row number to the variable.

```
$csvdata=Import-Csv $file.FullName 

write-host $csvdata.Length

foreach($logInCsv in $csvdata)
{
    where $logInCsv.Batch_ID=$logInCsv.Length-1
    {
        $batchID=$logInCsv.Batch_ID
        $transactionID=$logInCsv.Transaction_id
        $printDate=$logInCsv.Date
    }

    Write-Host $batchID $transactionID $printDate
}
```

Comment: with `Get-Content`, the `-TotalCount` parameter will grab that many lines from the start of the file. then the `-Tail` parameter will grab that many lines from the END of the file. you need to run it twice, tho, since the two parameters are not allowed in the same call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using them, it works fine for -TotalCount but when I use -Tail i get lot of empty cells

Comment: $dummy=Get-Content $file.FullName -TotalCount 2

    $dummy1=Get-Content $file.FullName -Tail 4

Comment: without the file to look at, i can't guess why you are getting empty cells. the most likely cause is that the cells are actually empty ... [*grin*]

Comment: If it is about 3000 lines, I think that there is no problem reading all and filtering it. `([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file.FullName) -ne "")[0,1,-1] | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv $file.FullName 
$csvdata | Select-Object -First 1
$csvdata | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: This is working, but how do I assign it to a variable, when I assign it and then send it as a mail body i get the object itself.

Comment: Eg: @{Batch_Id=2129475} @{Batch_Id=2138701}

Comment: I modified the code as per my need <br/> $firstElement=$getBatchIds | Select-Object -First 1 -property Batch_Id
    $lastElement=$getBatchIds | Select-Object -Last 1  -property Batch_Id

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to iterate the Rows,
once imported the index of the first and last is sufficient.

With a sample input file:

```
> Get-Content .\SO_56497517.csv
BatchID,Transprinted,Date
1,abc,2019-01-13
2,def,2019-03-15
3,xyz,2019-06-06
```

This script:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\07\SO_56497517.ps1
$File = Get-Item '.\So_56497517.Csv'
$Csvdata=(Import-Csv $File.FullName)[0,-1]
$Csvdata
```

yields this output:

```
BatchID Transprinted Date
------- ------------ ----
1       abc          2019-01-13
3       xyz          2019-06-06
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first and last (without empty Cells):

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv $file.FullName 
#re-assign without empty Cells
$csvdata = $csvdata | Where-Object {-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.ColumName))} 
$csvdata | Select-Object -First 1
$csvdata | Select-Object -Last 1
```